# How to configure Xmn for Spark executor

Tags: performance, apache-spark, garbage-collection, jvm, executor

In the doc of Spark GC Tuning (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning), it says increasing Young generation using the option -Xmn when there are too many minor GC. I've tried putting it in "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", but doesn't work. Where should I configure this JVM settings?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a false alarm. It works with the following configurations 
 spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Xmn1g -verbose:gc -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution"